# No default debit and credit account defined on journal - Odoo v13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I have created a point of sale and I have changed the currency in the journals from USD to MXN, when closing the point of sale, I get the following error: "No default debit and credit account defined on journal Efectivo (ids: [10 ]). "

I understand that I must go to the Efectivo journal and there place the default debit and credit data. But there is nothing like that in the journal.

[image: Odoo_image]

I have changed the journal to Sales, Bank and each of the options in the drop-down list, none of them comes "Debit" or "Credit account"

All this happens when you change the currency from USD to MXN.

I have tried this in different ways, in different databases, with and without demo information and I always get the same error.

I don't know what to do to repair it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue.

i went to the terminal and connected to my DB:

There i find the column `default_credit_account_id` and `default_debit_account_id` and it was empty on `account_journal`.

The others had a integer value.

`select * from account_journal`

So i guess these values comes from `account_account`, and since i am defining cash (Efectivo), i selected that.

`select * from account_account`

You can query that table and verify that which account do you want.

Finally i update the table `account_journal`.

`update account_journal set default_credit_account_id = 39, default_debit_account_id = 39 where id=11;`

Remember, the `id` is from your `account_journal`